# Difference between liquid and solid stearic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I had some stearic acid in solid pellet format. It is slippy and in white color. I used this to make some experiments. I recently notice that some manufacturer can supply liquid stearic acid. I checked the books. Stearic acid should be in solid form at room temperature. I was confused.
Would someone help me to understand what is the liquid form stearic acid? What is the difference with the solid form? Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you link to the products in question or provide more information about them.

Comment: https://mateossl.es/stearic-acid-2/?lang=en. Click on the Stearic acid supply format. I found other Chinese suppliers (no English available) supply liquid format too.

Comment: Another one in India https://m.indiamart.com/proddetail/stearic-acid-5004037191.html

Comment: The liquid form must be shipped in heated tanks...

Comment: One should ask the supplier. Unless a SE user has direct knowledge, it is hard to say what is used to make what would be basically a solution or an emulsion.